# Is it possible to use yubikey with server AD which is already in sync with Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, yubico

I am planning to use Yubikey with my systems.  Currently I have my windows server Active directory is configured to synchronize  with Microsoft AD services. So if I use Yubikey in my server for 2FA, will it cause any problem with synchronizing of server AD with Azure AD?.

If no issues how can i configure yubikey?